# Yajra How to parsing ID from html to ajax without using onclick

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, yajra-datatable

I have a datatable with more than 1 tab. I want to display my data from post's table into the datatable, but in My post table I have LanguageID column. So, I want to separate the data by LanguageID and that's why I am using tab. But, I got problem when I want to get the LanguageID.

This is my view.. Sorry I can not post the code and using Image because I have @foreach in my code.

[image]

and this is my ajax

```
$(function() {
  var id = 1;
  var oTable = $("#data-post" + id).DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "{{ url("
      post ") }}",
      data: function(d) {
        d.LanguageID = id;
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        data: 'PostDate',
        name: 'PostDate'
      },
      {
        data: 'PostTitle',
        name: 'PostTitle'
      },
      {
        data: 'PostSlug',
        name: 'PostTitle'
      },
      {
        data: 'action',
        name: 'action'
      }
    ]
  });

  $('#tabPost' + id).on('click', function(e) {
    oTable.draw();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

I want to parse {{$language->id}} from html into my ajax.. but I don't know how to do that without using function onclick

Comment: You need to filter those posts that are related to a language. right?

Comment: yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem why I can't get the id, that is because I only get the first id.. So, I decide to use each to get all the id

```
$('.tabPost').each(function(){
var lang_id = $(this).attr('id');
var oTable = $("#data-post" + lang_id).DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax:{
    url: "{{ url("post") }}",
    data: function(d) {
      d.LanguageID = lang_id
    }
  },
  columns: [
      { data: 'PostDate', name: 'PostDate'},
      { data: 'PostTitle', name: 'PostTitle' },
      { data: 'PostSlug', name: 'PostTitle' },
      { data: 'action', name: 'action'}
  ]
});

$('#'+lang_id).on('click', function(e){
  oTable.draw();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Add language_id to your DataTable, but make it invisible. It is better to put it in the very first columns. (Later if you need to add columns, you won't need to modify your scripts)

Then when you click on the tabs, filter DataTable base on the invisible language_id column using the following script;

Tabs:

```
@foreach($languages as $language)                 
    <li>
        <a href="#lang-{{ $language->id }}" class="language-tab" data-language-id="{{ $language->id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ $language->title }}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Scripts (I assumed you have your invisible language column in the second column)

```
$('a.language-tab').click(function () {        
    table.api().columns(1).search($(this).attr('data-language-id'), false, false, true).draw();
});
```

You also can have an `All` tabas that show all posts from all languages.

Tabs

```
<li>
    <a href="#lang-all" class="language-tab" data-language-id="all" data-toggle="tab">All Languages</a>
</li>
@foreach($languages as $language)                 
    <li>
        <a href="#lang-{{ $language->id }}" class="language-tab" data-language-id="{{ $language->id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ $language->title }}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Scripts:

```
$('a.language-tab').click(function () {        
    if ($(this).attr('data-language-id') == 'all')
        table.api().columns(1).search('', false, false, true).draw();
    else                               
        table.api().columns(1).search($(this).attr('data-status-id'), false, false, true).draw();
});
```

You also can filter DataTable on its very first ajax request(something like **default filtering**).

```
'data' => "function (data) {                                                     
    data.columns[1].search.value = '{{ $language->id }}'
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use click function.. because I want the data display first before I click

Comment: @jamesriady take a look at last part of my answer.

Comment: table is not defined.. it does not know what is table.api().. maybe I have simple way. but I don't know to get it.. I think that I only need to take the id from html and make it as a looping variable on my jquery

Comment: The data is null.. I don't get the data.. Do you have any idea to make {{$language->id}} as a variable on my jquery? I am using attribute, but it only take the first id

Comment: You mean this `var id = {{ $language->id }}` in the begining?

Comment: I have found what I need.. I only need to use each() to get all id.. Thankyou for your time to help me.